# Double-slit experiment with molecules and interference pattern

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, double-slit-experiment

Is it true that in the double-slit experiment with molecules a which-way measurement is performed and the interference pattern is not destroyed?

We know exactly which slit the molecule goes through.. and the interference pattern is not lost?!

(*I have read that when a which-way measurement is performed in the double-slit experiment with **electrons**, it completely ruins the interference pattern.*

*Maybe this is because electrons are much smaller than molecules and exhibit stronger wave-like behaviours. The collapse of the wave function due to observation is much more pronounced with electrons compared to single molecules, and this results in the complete destruction of the interference pattern. The collapse of the wave function is more pronounced with electrons compared to single molecules*.)

Comment: If you know which way a particle took, you excluded the the other path, so there's nothing to interfere with. Could you show us the source which claims the opposite?

Comment: @A.P. Weak measurement.

Comment: I actually meant a journal article or textbook chapter. Otherwise, I can only guess what you mean. Maybe have a look into [B.-G. Englert – _Fringe Visibility and Which-Way Information: An Inequality_](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.2154). The key statement is: The more certain you are about the path, the less visible the interference pattern.

Comment: @A.P. Exactly..